# How to get value in for-loop python

Tags: python, for-loop

I made for loop command as follows:

```
for i in range(1,4):
    x = [i, i*2, i*3]
    print(x)
```

The above result of for-loop command and the final value x are

```
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 4, 6]
[3, 6, 9]

>>> x
[3,6,9]
```

But I want to get every x while this command iterate in for-loop.
For example, I guess sequential values of list x such as

```
x1 = [1,2,3]
x2 = [2,4,6]
x3 = [3,6,9]
```

I ultimately want to get 3x3 matrix form of X.

```
X = [[1,2,3],
     [2,4,6],
     [3,6,9]]
```

However, I don't know the way to get each list x value or make X matrix.

Comment: If you are doing a lot of matrix/array computations with Python, you might find the NumPy library useful.  In this case, you could use `np.arange(1, 4)[:, None] * np.arange(1, 4)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way using a simple `for` loop. First initialise a list. Then append a list to this list during each iteration.

```
res = []
for i in range(1, 4):
    res.append([i, i*2, i*3])

print(res)

[[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6], [3, 6, 9]]
```

---

The Pythonic way would be to use a list comprehension:

```
res = [[i, i*2, i*3] for i in range(1, 4)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
X = [[k*i for i in range(1,4)] for k in range(1, 4)]

print(X)
>>>[[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6], [3, 6, 9]]
```

With this method you can easily modify it for any size matrix of this type, i.e. one for a 4 by 4 matrix can be generated with

```
[[k*i for i in range(1,5)] for k in range(1, 5)]
>>>[[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 4, 6, 8], [3, 6, 9, 12], [4, 8, 12, 16]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make a second list and append it to x

```
x = []
for i in range(1,4):
    temp = [i, i*2, i*3]
    x.append(temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

why not create a list and then append more lists to it like this:

```
x = []
for in in range(1,4):
    x.append([i, i*2, i*3])

print(x)
# [[1,2,3],
# [2,4,6],
# [3,6,9]]
```

Comment: Please make this a full answer, not just a code answer with no explanation.

Comment: @petezurich Should be fixed now